# Form with textfield and grid: send all values to the server

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In create and update forms, it is sometimes necessary to give the user the ability to dynamically add fields to values of the same type (more than one phone, more than one address, etc.).

I'm exploring several possibilities to do this.

One of them is to use a grid as a form field.

However, I have doubts about how best to implement this idea, especially on how to send all the form field values (textfield and grid) to the server (and then how to load them later in the form to edit).

Fiddles with some ideas:

One with cellediting plugin https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ftp

Another one with roweditin gplugin a https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fto

Comment: Why not putting an "add" button next to each phone field and insert another phone field on press ? Form sends all fields inside. Also, it would be trivial to insert multiple phone fields on form load to edit.

Comment: @abeyaz sometimes multiple sets of fields would be necessary, and in such cases it may be preferable to opt for the great potentiality of the grid component. Thanks for de ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the "best to implement", but I have seen so many requirements for multivalue input, that for reusability I have in my toolbox a gridfield similar to the following one:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.GridField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
    alias: 'widget.gridfield',
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        if(!me.columns) me.columns = {
             dataIndex: 'field1'
        };
        if(!me.mapFn) me.mapFn = function(value) {
            if(Ext.isObject(value)) return value;
            return {
                field1: value
            };
        };
        if(!me.unmapFn) me.unmapFn = function(record) {
            return record.get('field1');
        };
        me.grid = Ext.widget(Ext.apply({
            xtype: 'grid',
            viewConfig: {
                markDirty: false
            },
            store: me.store || Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: me.columns.map(function(column) {
                    return {
                        name: column.dataIndex,
                        type: column.dataType || 'auto',
                        defaultValue: column.defaultValue
                    };
                }),
                listeners: {
                    update: me.updateValue,
                    datachanged: me.updateValue,
                    scope: me
                }
            }),
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                getClass: function () {
                    return 'x-fa fa-times'
                },
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {
                    grid.getStore().remove(record);
                },
                width: 35
            }].concat(me.columns),
            bbar: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-pencil',
                text: 'Add',
                handler: function(btn) {
                    var grid = btn.up('grid'),
                        store = grid.getStore(),
                        record = store.add(Ext.clone(me.emptyRecord) || {})[0];
                    grid.getPlugin('editor').startEditByPosition({
                        row: store.indexOf(record),
                        column: 1
                    });
                }
            }],
            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                    pluginId: 'editor',
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                })
            ]
        }, me.gridConfig)); // "gridConfig" config can override everything on each instance.
        me.hiddenField = Ext.widget({
            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
            name: me.name,
            value: '',
            allowNull: false,
            rawToValue: function (raw) {
                return raw;
            },
            valueToRaw: function (value) {
                return value;
            },
            getRawValue: function () {
                return Ext.valueFrom(this.rawValue, '')
            },
            isEqual: function (a, b) {
                return Ext.encode(a) == Ext.encode(b)
            },
            listeners: {
                change: function(field, nV, oV) {
                    if(!Ext.isArray(nV)) nV = [nV];
                    var store = me.grid.getStore();
                    store.removeAll();
                    store.add(nV.map(me.mapFn));
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.apply(me, {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype:'container',
                border: 1,
                style: {
                    borderColor: '#d0d0d0',
                    borderStyle: 'solid'
                },
                items: [me.grid]
            }, me.hiddenField]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    updateValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            grid = me.grid,
            hiddenField = me.hiddenField,
            nV = grid.getStore().getRange().map(me.unmapFn, me),
            oV = me.hiddenField.getValue();
        if(!oV || Ext.isArray(oV) && Ext.encode(nV) != Ext.encode(oV)) {
            hiddenField.suspendCheckChange++;
            hiddenField.setValue(nV);
            hiddenField.suspendCheckChange--;
            me.fireEvent('change', me, nV, oV);
        }
    }
});
```

which can then be used like this:

```
},{
    xtype: 'gridfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Contacts',
    name: 'contacts',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Type',
        dataIndex: 'type',
        editor:{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'type',
            valueField: 'name',
            displayField: 'name',
            store: combostore,
            queryMode: 'local'
        },
        flex: 0.7
    },{
        text: 'Description',
        dataIndex: 'description',
        editor:{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'description'
        },
        flex: 1
    }],
    mapFn: function(value) {
        return value;
    },
    unmapFn: function(record) {
        return record.getData();
    }
}, {
```

I have made a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ftq) for you based on your fiddle, including working load and save operations on the form, but in ExtJS 6.x. And I have [checked that it works with ExtJS 5 as well](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ftr), although you have to add working icons.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. A great help (as always). Your example is very complete and it helps me a lot. I like this solution.
I will study it line by line (and try to understand everything correctly).

Comment: Alexandre, the component works fine, but I have a question in the update. I tried with a single query (using PHP and MYSQL) to bring in the store, in each row, all the data needed for record update, but I did not get it in relation to the data needed for the gridfield (multivalue). How do you do this? the data is already all available in the store or when you select the record to edit you make a new request by sending the id of that particular record to filter the necessary data to the gridfield?