# Grid of values in form in ext.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Theoretical question here,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1xfv.png

Based on this screenshot, I need to have a form with a normal text field (easy-peasy), and image picker that feeds from a custom backend server source, and a grid.

This needs to be able to handle a brand new record being created, and also accept a saved record to be loaded for editing, meaning a user can fill out all fields, including creating as many grid rows as they want and adding products to each, or when they load an existing answer, the grid populates with each record of a product weight.

What I need to know is this. Is all of this possible together, or not? If this is not possible, is there a better way to achieve the above functionality? I am completely new to the ext.js framework as of a week ago, and while I'm perfectly comfortable crafting something like this from scratch with jQuery and Ajax coupled to my backend system in salesforce commerce cloud, I haven't been able to find any real examples of what I want to do yet in the ext.js community.

Examples that are close to what i'm wanting completely welcome if you got em, as well as any references to better places to ask this question.

Using ext.js 5.

Comment: Yes, they are doable, but not working out of the box. [I answered a similar question a few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958374/form-with-textfield-and-grid-send-all-values-to-the-server/49959417#49959417) which works with ExtJS6 and ExtJS5.

Comment: @Alexander This was extraordinarily helpful, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form with textfield and grid: send all values to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958374/form-with-textfield-and-grid-send-all-values-to-the-server)